# Django change FileInput "Browse... and No File Selected" text

Tags: html, django, django-forms

I want to change the **Browse.. | no file selected** text in a FileInput. How can I do that? I already declared `LANGUAGE_CODE = 'es'` in my settings.py, but the FileInput still renders the button in english.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The upload control has nothing to do with your Django language. It uses the browser user interface language. You can localize your upload fields using custom HTML only. See http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/inputfile.html for an example.